# Is it considered proper English to say "You best be..." or "You'd best..."?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, auxiliary-verbs

Often, I hear people say something like this:

> You best be going.

Or:

> You'd best sweep the floor before you leave.

Essentially, *you'd best/you best be* just means *you should*. Is it grammatically correct to use these phrases?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Had best" is correct, but "had better" is more common.  "Has best" is usually associated with dialects, such as in the American South. [Source](http://books.google.com/books?id=WCCk829jmzUC&pg=PA309&lpg=PA309&dq=%22had%20best%22%20grammar&source=bl&ots=iHNQs6mzfq&sig=B6vY2uykYy7rnzJPo-7nqJKIWRo&hl=en&ei=9MO9Tu6VFtDD0AGIkLH4BA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=had%20best&f=false)

One can think of them as forms of:

> It would be better if you did that.
>
> It would be best if you did that.

"You best" is slang, omitting the 'had', and not correct.

Comment: This idiom sounds rather aggressive to me, carrying an implied threat that the speaker will take some undesired action if the listener does not do what is suggested.

Comment: It can be used that way, certainly, but not always.  "You'd best catch that cup before it falls!"

Answer (score 4):

Sentences such as *You'd best be going* and *You'd better be going* are fairly common in British English and *You best . . .* might occur as an elided form of *You'd best . . .* They are perhaps most frequently found in speech, but I wouldn't be surprised to find even in some academic writing something like *I had better set out my position now to avoid misunderstanding later on.*

Answer (score 2):

'you best...' (and 'you better...') are both grammatical and productive (you can change the tense and the person).

It's not identical to 'should' but they share a lot in meaning. It often cones in the pattern:

> they had better (do something) or (something else unwanted will happen).

It's not very formal so that's why it probably sounds wrong to use in certain contexts.